# ionic: where to see the displayed console log

Tags: ionic-framework, console.log

I am new to ionic I am following [ionic framework documents](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/action-sheet/ActionSheetController/) to learn it.

Here is my method's code: **hello-ionic.ts**

```
  openActionSheet(){
    let actionSheet=this.actionsheetCtrl.create(
    {
        title: 'Modify your album',
        cssClass: 'page-hello-ionic',
        buttons:[
          {
            text: 'Delete',
            role: 'destructive', //will always sort to be on top
            icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'trash' : null,
            handler: () => {
              console.log('Delete clicked');
            }
          },
          {
          text: 'Play',
          icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'arrow-dropright-circle' : null,
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Play clicked');
          }   
        },
        {
          text: 'Favorite',
          icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'heart-outline' : null,
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Favorite clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel', // will always sort to be on the bottom
          icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'close' : null,
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        }
      ]});
    actionSheet.present();
  }
```

The code works fine. But I want to know that where is `console.log()` printed. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: r u developing mobile app or web app ?

Comment: mobile app. but, I am also using `ionic serve` command to check it in the web.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To check the console log you can use browser and run the below command:

**Step 1:** `$ionic serve` (will run your app on localhost)

**Step 2:** In your respective browser (chrome, safari, etc...) where your app is running <kbd>Right</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> and **inspect** your app as per below screenshot.

[image]

**Step 3:** You will get a window with HTML elements on the right side of your browser window and on the left your app screen.

[image]

**Step 4:** On the right side window, you can find "Console" menu option on the top bar. Click on that you will get your console where you find your app **logs** or **error** or **warning** which ionic generated.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**
*Real Device or Emulator debugging*

To check `real-device` or `emulator` or `genymotion` console logs follow the below steps & screenshots.

**Step 1:** Run this command to run your app on real-device or emulator

```
$ionic cordova run android
```

**Step 2:** After successfully launch the app on device or emulator Go to Chrome browser and <kbd>Right</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> and click on **"Inspect"** and you will get below screen at bottom of your browser.

[image]

**Step 3:** Click on **"Remote devices"** will show connected real device or emulator list.

From that device list click on **"Inspect"** button on the right side of that device name(*check screenshot for the same*) will open a new window with your device mirror now console is yours play around with this debugger.

[image]

[image]

Hope this will help you to debug your app.

Comment: one more question. how can I see log in mobile

Comment: on which device Android or iOS ?

Comment: Did you check the log level in the console? change it from "default levels" to all.

Comment: may be outdated. remote devices are not found currently by default in chrome.
if you can't find, type this in the browser url -> chrome://inspect/#devices

Answer (score 7):

> if you want to get Live console logs in the ionic application (real
> device or emulator)

```
ionic cordova run android --livereload  --consolelogs --serverlogs
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use chrome inspect to get console logs while debugging with emulator.
open chrome and enter following :

chrome://inspect:device

you can see ionic device listed in the devices and you can use inspect and check the console.logs as described [in this video](https://youtu.be/NBXjlIRw4ek)

Answer (score 2):

When I test websites on mobile using Ionic, I usually prefer not to run the `Remote devices` window as I need to choose the mobile, then tons of tabs in my mobile browser - then `inspect` and after a refresh on mobile - it disconnect ...

For real debugging purposes, I prefer running Ionic with `-c` like so, and then I see the console in the terminal w/o anything being disconnected.

```
my-server$ ionic serve -c --no-open --address 192.168.1.112

[INFO] Development server running!
       Local: http://192.168.1.112:8100    
       Use Ctrl+C to quit this process
```

Browsing in my mobile device to: http://192.168.1.112:8100

logs will appear in terminal where I run Ionic cli:

```
[app-scripts] [09:49:42]  console.log: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production
[app-scripts]             mode.
[app-scripts] [09:49:42]  console.log: cookieEnabled: true
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Test on iOs

1. Run `ionic capacitor run ios --livereload`, this will show you a list with the iPhone emulators options, choose the one that you want and it will be opened
2. After the application be opened in the emulator you have to go and open the Safari browser, then in the top options go-to `develop->simulator->localhost` and that will open a window which will show you the logs that you want

#### Test on Android

3. Run `ionic capacitor run android --livereload` this will show you a list with the Android device emulators that you have created on Android Studio (be sure to have Android Studio and adb properly installed, updated and configurated), choose the one that you want and it will be opened
4. After the application be opened in the emulator you have to go and open the Google Chrome browser, then go to `chrome://inspect/#devices` and find your emulated or physical device in the bottom list (some times could take a few minutes to appear) and then click on `inspect` after that, a console window will be open and you will be able to see all your logs

NOTE: This has been done and tested on Ionic 5

Answer (score 0):

Please use web browser to see the console logs.

Run the `ionic serve` command by terminal to run the ionic in your browser.

If you couldn't see the console logs in your browser, simply use `console.warn`... it's a alternative solution to see the logs

Comment: To see the console logs in the browser: Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/log/ - Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console - Safari: https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/